# How to break a bash loop by output of an internal script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a simple bash loop running a series of scripts as

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( c=0; c<=200; c++ ))
do  
php ./script.php $1
done
```

Is it possible to break the `loop` by the `output` `echo`ed from the `php` script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you mean something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( c=0; c<=200; c++ ))
do
    output=$(php ./script.php "$1")
    case $output in
      *'foo'*) echo "Loop terminated"; break;; 
    esac
    echo "$output"
done
```

Inspired by [@Archemar's answer](/a/362121/19240), you could also say

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( c=0; c<=200; c++ ))
do
    ! php ./script.php "$1" | grep -v 'foo' || break
done
```

Answer (score 1):

if script.php can return something different than 0.

```
 ...
 do
 if ! php ./script.php $1
 then break 
 fi
 done
```

- I am not sure you need `./` in front of script.php
- <s>I am also unsure of your loop syntax</s> I learn something about bash

to filter on "output"

```
if php script.php $1 | grep --quiet output
then break
fi
```

this way, this is `grep` that give `if` the return code.

Comment: The C-style `for` loop syntax is a Bash extension.

Comment: The `grep` will filter out the output from the PHP script completely. To avoid that, `! php script.php "$1" | grep -v output || break`

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like this:

```
output=$(php script.php "$1")
if [ $output = "{End output}" ]
then
     break
fi
```

Now you only have to change your PHP script on this way:

```
...
echo '{End output}';
...
```

**Update:**

Thanks to tripleee for the advices. I changed it (I hope like he meant it :-) )

Comment: You should avoid using uppercase for your private variables; uppercase names are reserved for system use.

Comment: You can't have spaces around the equals sign in the assignment.

Comment: No, that's not what triplee meant. You can't have spaces around the assignment operator (`var=foo`), you can  in the test (`[ var = value ]`). I fixed the syntax error but pelase try to test before posting next time.